# How do I access no_monitor in save() function?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've this `configure()` function in my form:

```
public function configure() {
    $this->current_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();

    unset($this['updated_at'], $this['created_at']);

    $this->widgetSchema['idempresa'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
    $id_empresa = $this->current_user->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
    $this->setDefault('idempresa', $id_empresa);

    $this->widgetSchema['no_emisor'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'SdrivingEmisor', 'add_empty' => 'Seleccione un Emisor', 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['idempresa'] = new sfValidatorPass();
    $this->validatorSchema['no_emisor'] = new sfValidatorPass();
}
```

And I'm need to define a relation data in `save()` function so I do this:

```
public function save($con = null) {
    $new_machine = parent::save($con);

    $relation = new SdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
    $relation->setIdmaquina($new_machine);
    $relation->setIdemisor();
    $relation->save();

    return $new_machine;
}
```

In order the set the `Idemisor`, how do I access to the selected value when users submit the form? Is this the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
After take the suggestion about how to access `no_emisor` value now my code looks like:

```
public function save($con = null) {
    $new_machine = parent::save($con);

    $relation = new SdrivingMaquinaEmisor();
    $relation->setIdmaquina($new_machine);
    $relation->setIdemisor($this->values['no_emisor']);
    $relation->save();

    return $new_machine;
}
```

But I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idmaquina' cannot be null

For some reason `$new_machine` doesn't return the `id` of the latest saved element. Maybe I'm doing in the wrong way so what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to do this in the form's `doUpdateObject` instead, since that receives the cleaned values.

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormObject#method_doupdateobject

Edit:

Alternatively, `$this->values['no_emisor']` should work once the form has been bound.

Comment: maybe but this method has worked for me some other times, I just don't know how to get the value of `no_emisor`